# Rust proc_macro and syn: parse whitespace

Tags: parsing, rust, macros, whitespace

I'm trying to write a proc macro `block!` that parses syntax vaguely resembling jsx/rsx using `syn` crate.
The following should be parsed into a block `"wrapper"` with two children blocks `"text_1"` and `"text_2"`:

```
let block = block! {
    <"wrapper">
      <"text_1">("hello")
      <"text_2">("world")
};
```

Using `input.parse::<syn::Token![]>()` when implementing `syn::parse` I can parse everything alright.

However there's one thing that I can't find a solution to: I want to enforce the style of code for *wrapper-children* relation so that if some block is nested it has to have double space or a tabulation before it **e.g.**

```
// -- Good --
let block = block! {
  <"text_1">("hello")
  <"text_2">("world")
};

// -- Good --
let block = block! {
  <"wrapper">
    <"text_1">("hello")
    <"text_2">("world")
};

// -- Bad --
// Need spaces/tabs before the children tags
let block = block! {
  <"wrapper">
  <"text_1">("hello")
  <"text_2">("world")
};
```

Parsing `TokenStream` by `Token![<]`, `parse::<LitStr>()`, `Token![>]`, `parenthesized!` and `bracketed!` doesn't enforce intended rules, but I can't find anything related to parsing tabs/spaces in `syn` docs.

Judging by `TokenStream` printed in console - it doesn't even have anything between wrapper's `>` and `<` of the first child

```
Input: TokenStream [
    Punct {
        ch: '<',
        spacing: Alone,
        span: #0 bytes(118..119),
    },
    Literal {
        kind: Str,
        symbol: "wrapper",
        suffix: None,
        span: #0 bytes(119..128),
    },
    Punct {
        ch: '>',
        spacing: Alone,
        span: #0 bytes(128..129),
    },
    Punct {
        ch: '<',
        spacing: Alone,
        span: #0 bytes(144..145),
    },
    Literal {
        kind: Str,
        symbol: "text_1",
        suffix: None,
        span: #0 bytes(145..153),
    },
    Punct {
        ch: '>',
        spacing: Alone,
        span: #0 bytes(153..154),
    },
```

Any advise on how it's possible? If possible at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation is not significant in Rust's syntax and whitespace is only required occasionaly to separate what would be a single token into two tokens (think `let name`). So because its only functional purpose is to help parse tokens, whitespace is not itself a token.

If your desired macro syntax *relies* on indentation, then you should use a string literal instead:

```rust
let block = block!(r#"
    <"wrapper">
        <"text_1">("hello")
        <"text_2">("world")
"#);
```

---

However, there is a hacky way to get what you want since [`Span`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.Span.html)s associated with tokens have a [`.source_text()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.Span.html#method.source_text) method. Here's a simple macro that takes the source and turns it into a literal:

```
use proc_macro::{Literal, TokenStream, TokenTree};

#[proc_macro]
pub fn block(tokens: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let source = tokens
        .into_iter()
        .next()
        .unwrap()
        .span()
        .source_text()
        .unwrap();

    TokenTree::Literal(Literal::string(&source)).into()
}
```

```
use macros::block;

fn main() {
    let block = block! { {
        <"wrapper">
          <"text_1">("hello")
          <"text_2">("world")
    } };

    dbg!(block);
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:10] block = "{\n        <\"wrapper\">\n          <\"text_1\">(\"hello\")\n          <\"text_2\">(\"world\")\n    }"
```

You could then parse it by lines and compare the leading whitespace within yuour procedural macro. Do notice though that I added an extra `{ }` since a `TokenStream` itself doesn't have an encompassing `.span()` available.

You should also heed the documentation that this is not an intended use-case:

> Returns the source text behind a span. This preserves the original source code, including spaces and comments. It only returns a result if the span corresponds to real source code.
>
> Note: The observable result of a macro should only rely on the tokens and not on this source text. The result of this function is a best effort to be used for diagnostics only.

**I do not encourage you to actually do this.** And as much good intentions I'm sure you have, a macro should *not* be enforcing style.

Comment: This is cute for hacking, but doing things the documentation explicitly says is not supported is... not recommended (yes, I know you already warned about that).

Comment: I also noticed that there is an actual info on span bytes `span: #0 bytes(128..129)` so theoretically I can assume how many spaces there's between parent and child by counting bytes, not sure if it's useful though

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible. Proc macros gets their tokens without whitespaces or comments, they're erased before.

What is possible (though maybe not desired) is to take a giant string literal and work with it. Strings preserve whitespaces.